# Join tables based on multiple ranges in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I have a situation where I have two data frames I would like to join. The table
`params` describes the param for a unit in terms time and angle ranges. The table `data` is longer and contains id, time and angle parameters.

I would like to join the param value from `params` when id match and time is in the range between valid_from and valid_to and ang is between angle_begin angle_end in the `data` table.

Below is an example of the tables.

```
params <- data.frame(id = 1:4
                    ,valid_from  = 1
                    ,valid_to    = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
                    ,angle_begin = c(120, 90, 0, 50)
                    ,angle_end   = c(180, 170, 160, 150)
                    ,param       = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each=100)
                  ,time = rep(seq(from = 0.5, to = 50, by = 0.5), 4)
                  ,ang  = rep(runif(100, 0, 360), 4))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `tidyverse`, you can try something like:

```
data %>%
  inner_join(params) %>%
  filter( time > valid_from & time < valid_to) %>%
  filter( ang > angle_begin & ang < angle_end)
```

Answer (score 11):

With `data.table` this is a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
setDT(params)
setDT(data)

# keep only rows of data with matches in params
data[params, 
     on = .(id, time >= valid_from, time <= valid_to, ang >= angle_begin, ang <= angle_end),
     .(id, time = x.time, ang = x.ang, param)]
```

> ```
>     id time        ang param
>  1:  1  2.0 140.383052     A
>  2:  1  3.5 152.772925     A
>  3:  1  8.0 141.039548     A
>  4:  2  1.0 104.434264     B
>  5:  2  2.0 140.383052     B
>  6:  2  3.5 152.772925     B
>  7:  2  8.0 141.039548     B
>  8:  2 16.0 150.424306     B
>  9:  2 16.5  92.201187     B
> 10:  ...
> 41:  4 22.0  89.813795     D
> 42:  4 22.5 131.004229     D
> 43:  4 26.0  79.839443     D
> 44:  4 27.5 128.291356     D
> 45:  4 29.0 127.942287     D
> 46:  4 30.0 136.388594     D
> 47:  4 32.0 140.092817     D
> 48:  4 32.5 108.346831     D
> 49:  4 37.0 140.732844     D
>     id time        ang param
> ```

If all rows of `data` should be kept

```
params[data, 
       on = .(id, valid_from <= time, valid_to >= time, angle_begin <= ang, angle_end >= ang), 
       .(id, time = i.time, ang = i.ang, param)]
```

> ```
>      id time       ang param
>   1:  1  0.5 106.62639    NA
>   2:  1  1.0 104.43426    NA
>   3:  1  1.5  15.77429    NA
>   4:  1  2.0 140.38305     A
>   5:  1  2.5 322.31929    NA
>  ---                        
> 396:  4 48.0 131.17405    NA
> 397:  4 48.5 335.47857    NA
> 398:  4 49.0 181.64450    NA
> 399:  4 49.5  90.96224    NA
> 400:  4 50.0  60.04268    NA
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Given your wording, I interpret your question differently. That is, I read that you want to keep all rows but join only when the values of `valid_` and `angle_` are within the specified range. 
Also note that depending on whether you want to include values at the boundaries of the ranges you may need `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`.

Thus, starting from Aramis7d's answer:

```
data %>%
  inner_join(params, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(param = ifelse(
           time >= valid_from & time <= valid_to & 
             ang >= angle_begin & ang <= angle_end,
           param,
           NA))
```

Comment: It was indeed my intent. I used Aramis7d's answer and then ended the chain with a right_join(data). I believe this comes out the same.

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse way of doing this is using the `fuzzyjoin` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

params <- data.frame(id = 1:4
                     ,valid_from  = 1
                     ,valid_to    = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
                     ,angle_begin = c(120, 90, 0, 50)
                     ,angle_end   = c(180, 170, 160, 150)
                     ,param       = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each=100)
                   ,time = rep(seq(from = 0.5, to = 50, by = 0.5), 4)
                   ,ang  = rep(runif(100, 0, 360), 4))


fuzzy_left_join(data, params,
                by = c("id" = "id",
                       "time" = "valid_from",
                       "time" = "valid_to",
                       "ang" = "angle_begin",
                       "ang" = "angle_end"),
                match_fun = list(`==`, `>`, `<`, `>`, `<`)) %>%
  slice(1:10)
```

Credit to [mfherman](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881/2?u=moho).