# Aggregate column from a different length dataset with multiple ifelse conditions

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I have two datasets: one with waypoints and one with tracks.

I want to add the "mode" variable of the tracks dataset to the waypoints dataset depending on the time of the tracking

In the waypoints dataset, I have the variable "tracked_at"

`

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
tracked_at <- ymd_hms(c("2017-10-16 06:00:02", "2017-10-16 06:00:07", "2017-10-16 06:01:15", "2017-10-16 06:02:09",
                     "2017-10-16 06:02:50", "2017-10-16 06:04:05", "2017-10-16 06:04:15", "2017-10-16 06:10:15",
                     "2017-10-16 06:14:15", "2017-10-16 06:16:15", "2017-10-16 06:18:30", "2017-10-16 06:18:45", 
                     "2017-10-16 06:19:15", "2017-10-16 06:19:40", "2017-10-16 06:19:55", "2017-10-17 08:08:02", 
                     "2017-10-17 08:10:02", "2017-10-17 08:16:02", "2017-10-17 08:17:02", "2017-10-18 15:00:00"))

lat <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
long <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
id_user<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, tracked_at,lat, long, id_user )

print(df1)
   ID          tracked_at lat long id_user
1   1 2017-10-16 06:00:02   1    2       1
2   2 2017-10-16 06:00:07   1    2       1
3   3 2017-10-16 06:01:15   1    2       1
4   4 2017-10-16 06:02:09   1    2       1
5   5 2017-10-16 06:02:50   1    2       1
6   6 2017-10-16 06:04:05   1    2       1
7   7 2017-10-16 06:04:15   1    2       1
8   8 2017-10-16 06:10:15   1    2       1
9   9 2017-10-16 06:14:15   1    2       1
10 10 2017-10-16 06:16:15   1    2       1
11 11 2017-10-16 06:18:30   1    2       1
12 12 2017-10-16 06:18:45   1    2       1
13 13 2017-10-16 06:19:15   1    2       1
14 14 2017-10-16 06:19:40   1    2       1
15 15 2017-10-16 06:19:55   1    2       1
16 16 2017-10-17 08:08:02   1    2       2
17 17 2017-10-17 08:10:02   1    2       2
18 18 2017-10-17 08:16:02   1    2       2
19 19 2017-10-17 08:17:02   1    2       2
20 20 2017-10-18 15:00:00   1    2       3
```

In the tracks dataset, I have the variables "started_at" & "finished_a"

```
started_at <- ymd_hms(c("2017-10-16 06:00:05", "2017-10-16 06:04:15", "2017-10-16 06:18:31", "2017-10-17 08:10:02"))
finished_a <- ymd_hms(c("2017-10-16 06:02:10", "2017-10-16 06:18:30", "2017-10-16 06:19:45", "2017-10-17 08:16:02"))
id_user <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
Mode <- c("Walk", "Train", "Walk", "Car")
df2 <- data.frame(started_at,finished_a, id_user, Mode )
print(df2)

           started_at          finished_a id_user  Mode
1 2017-10-16 06:00:05 2017-10-16 06:02:10       1  Walk
2 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30       1 Train
3 2017-10-16 06:18:31 2017-10-16 06:19:45       1  Walk
4 2017-10-17 08:10:02 2017-10-17 08:16:02       2   Car
```

The 3 variables are date format (ymd_hms) and waypoints are also tracked when individuals are immobile, so the mode column should be fill most of the time by NA. I would like to add that in case NA are before the mode "Bus" or "Train" & after "Walk", then, it is "Waiting Time".

This would be the perfect dataset :

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
tracked_at <- ymd_hms(c("2017-10-16 06:00:02", "2017-10-16 06:00:07", "2017-10-16 06:01:15", "2017-10-16 06:02:09",
                 "2017-10-16 06:02:50", "2017-10-16 06:04:05", "2017-10-16 06:04:15", "2017-10-16 06:10:15",
                 "2017-10-16 06:14:15", "2017-10-16 06:16:15", "2017-10-16 06:18:30", "2017-10-16 06:18:45", 
                 "2017-10-16 06:19:15", "2017-10-16 06:19:40", "2017-10-16 06:19:55", "2017-10-17 08:08:02", 
                 "2017-10-17 08:10:02", "2017-10-17 08:16:02", "2017-10-17 08:17:02", "2017-10-18 15:00:00"))

lat <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
long <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
id_user<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
NeWmode <- c("NA","Walk", "Walk", "Walk", "Waiting Time", "Waiting Time", "Train", "Train", "Train", "Train", "Train",
             "Walk","Walk", "Walk", "NA", "NA", "Car", "Car", "NA", "NA")
df3 <- data.frame(ID, tracked_at,lat, long, id_user, Newmode )
print(df3)

ID              tracked_at lat long id_user      Newmode
1   1 2017-10-16 06:00:02   1    2       1           NA
2   2 2017-10-16 06:00:07   1    2       1         Walk
3   3 2017-10-16 06:01:15   1    2       1         Walk
4   4 2017-10-16 06:02:09   1    2       1         Walk
5   5 2017-10-16 06:02:50   1    2       1 Waiting Time
6   6 2017-10-16 06:04:05   1    2       1 Waiting Time
7   7 2017-10-16 06:04:15   1    2       1        Train
8   8 2017-10-16 06:10:15   1    2       1        Train
9   9 2017-10-16 06:14:15   1    2       1        Train
10 10 2017-10-16 06:16:15   1    2       1        Train
11 11 2017-10-16 06:18:30   1    2       1        Train
12 12 2017-10-16 06:18:45   1    2       1         Walk
13 13 2017-10-16 06:19:15   1    2       1         Walk
14 14 2017-10-16 06:19:40   1    2       1         Walk
15 15 2017-10-16 06:19:55   1    2       1           NA
16 16 2017-10-17 08:08:02   1    2       2           NA
17 17 2017-10-17 08:10:02   1    2       2          Car
18 18 2017-10-17 08:16:02   1    2       2          Car
19 19 2017-10-17 08:17:02   1    2       2           NA
20 20 2017-10-18 15:00:00   1    2       3           NA
```

My best guess was :

```
   id1 <-filter(df1, id_user==1) #filtering by users
id1Moda <- filter(df2, id_user==1)

id1Moda$mode.num[id1Moda$Mode=="Walk"] <-1
id1Moda$mode.num[id1Moda$Mode=="Train"] <-2
id1Moda$mode.num[id1Moda$Mode=="Car"] <-3

  id1$mode <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(id1Moda)){
  for(k in 1:nrow(id1)){
    if((id1$tracked_at[k] >= id1Moda$started_at[i]) & (id1$tracked_at[k] <= id1Moda$finished_a[i])){
      id1$Newmode[k] <- id1Moda$mode.num[i]
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I don't filter by users cause I have 50 users to analyse
Also, the loop is very very slow as the dataset is more than 280 000 points for that ID. The total database get together 38 000 000 data points.

Remarks:

1. Tracks does not necessarily start when a waypoint was recorded that is why I use an interval
2. In this try, I needed to pass the variable from factor to integer cause I did not succeed with this type of variable such as:  `id1Moda$mode.num[id1Moda$Mode=="Walk"] <-1`

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Use join and filters to accomplish your task. A inner join can be quite memory intensive for large datasets

Note I have changed the name of `finished_a` to `finished_at`

```
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by="id_user") %>% 
  filter(tracked_at >= started_at,  tracked_at <=finished_at)


   ID          tracked_at lat long id_user          started_at         finished_at  Mode
1   2 2017-10-16 06:00:07   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:00:05 2017-10-16 06:02:10  Walk
2   3 2017-10-16 06:01:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:00:05 2017-10-16 06:02:10  Walk
3   4 2017-10-16 06:02:09   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:00:05 2017-10-16 06:02:10  Walk
4   7 2017-10-16 06:04:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30 Train
5   8 2017-10-16 06:10:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30 Train
6   9 2017-10-16 06:14:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30 Train
7  10 2017-10-16 06:16:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30 Train
8  11 2017-10-16 06:18:30   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:04:15 2017-10-16 06:18:30 Train
9  12 2017-10-16 06:18:45   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:18:31 2017-10-16 06:19:45  Walk
10 13 2017-10-16 06:19:15   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:18:31 2017-10-16 06:19:45  Walk
11 14 2017-10-16 06:19:40   1    2       1 2017-10-16 06:18:31 2017-10-16 06:19:45  Walk
12 17 2017-10-17 08:10:02   1    2       2 2017-10-17 08:10:02 2017-10-17 08:16:02   Car
13 18 2017-10-17 08:16:02   1    2       2 2017-10-17 08:10:02 2017-10-17 08:16:02   Car
```

a similar question is discussed in

[Join tables based on multiple ranges in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339638/join-tables-based-on-multiple-ranges-in-r)